# generating main arguments without the parameter

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

In C programming language, is it possible to access `int argc` or `char **argv` without using the parameters? I know some of you might ask why this is needed, just for research purposes.

Is it possible to generate the cmd line arguments  without using the main parameter variables ? For example, to illustrate some pseudo code, that i have in mind,

```
LPTSTR cmd  = GetCommandLine();
splitted = cmd.split(" ") //split from spaces
char **someArgv.pushForEach Splitted, length++
```

and you'd have a `someArgv` with the parameters and `length` as `argc`, this'd really help to know if possible to illustrate.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Please pick one.

Comment: done @Gerhardh chosen C as stated above now

Comment: smells like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you not use the right signature for `main` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: just having some modules loaded outside exe and wish to see how it'd work like this @Devolus

Comment: So yoou want to call some main function with your own set of parameters?

Comment: yes, possible, @Devolus generate a new main, change it depending on comparisons, many possible implementation, just wish to know how to produce an exact `char **argv` @Devolus

Comment: @turmuka If `cmd` is `"123 abc 456"`, you want to call `main(argc, argv)` such that `argc = 4` and `argv = { "", "123", "abc", "456", 0 }`?

Comment: if `cmd` is `"123 abc 456"` doesn't that meant `argc` would be 3 and `argv[argc]` would be `NULL` or am i wrong, is there an empty string ??  i guess not.

Comment: `argv[0]` is reserved for the program name.  `"123"` should be in `argv[1]`.

Comment: yes it is, i though `123` is the program name, yes then correct

Comment: @turmuka Hmm , yes my example for unclear on that point, yet I think I know what you looking for.

Comment: For Windows check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew

Comment: @turmuka Does `LPTSTR cmd  = GetCommandLine();` exists?  or is code needed for that too?

Comment: When you say "modules loaded outside exe", do you mean calling functions in a shared library?  If so, this isn't how you'd do it, mainly because such a module won't have a `main` function.  If you mean calling a separate program, you can do that with a function in the `exec` family.

Comment: yes such module won't have`main`function, that is why i cant use the main arguments, as i stated in the question above, again stating.. andyou can think of it as a shared library @dbush

Answer (score 1):

If OP [already has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027235/generating-main-arguments-without-the-parameter?noredirect=1#comment116741967_66027235) the command as a *string*, then:

- Form a copy of the string
- Parse it for argument count
- Allocate for `argv[]`
- Parse & tokenize copy for each `argv[]`
- Call `main()`

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Not standard, but commonly available
char *strdup(const char *s);

// Return length of token and adjust offset to the next one
// Adjust as needed
// Presently only ' ' are used to separate
// More advanced would have escape characters, other white-space, etc.
size_t tokenize(const char *s, size_t *offset) {
  // find following space
  size_t len = strcspn(s + *offset, " ");
  *offset += len;
  // find first non-space
  *offset += strspn(s + *offset, " ");
  return len;
}

int call_main(const char *cmd) {
  char *cmd2 = strdup(cmd);
  cmd2 += strspn(cmd2, " "); // skip leading spaces

  size_t offset = 0;
  int argc = 0;
  while (tokenize(cmd2, &offset) > 0) {
    argc++;
  }

  char **argv = malloc(sizeof *argv * ((unsigned)argc + 1u));
  offset = 0;
  for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
    argv[a] = &cmd2[offset];
    size_t len = tokenize(cmd2, &offset);
    argv[a][len] = '\0';
  }
  argv[argc] = NULL;

  int retval = 0;
#if 0
  retval = main(argc, argv);
#else
  printf("argc:%d argv:", argc);
  for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
    printf("%p \"%s\", ", argv[a], argv[a]);
  }
  printf("%p\n", argv[argc]);
#endif

  free(cmd2);
  free(argv);
  return retval;
}
```

Sample

```
int main() {
  call_main("  name 123  abc  456 ");
}

argc:4 argv:0x800062322 "name", 0x800062327 "123", 0x80006232c "abc", 0x800062331 "456", 0x0
```

---

Pedantic: The strings provided to `main()` should be modifiable.  Avoid code like

```
argv[1] = "Hello";
....
main(argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

int callMain(void)
{
    char *argv[4];

    argv[0] = "binary";
    argv[1] = "param1";
    argv[2] = "param2";
    argv[3] = NULL;

    return main(3, argv);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        return callMain();
    }

    printf("ARGC: %u\n", argc);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("ARG: %u - %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the only thing missing is **without using the main parameter variables** as OP stated

Comment: In this narrow case, `main()` declaration might be able to get by with  `int main();`.  One less occurrence of `argc, argv`.

Comment: If main was declared as `main()` then this implementation will not parse any arguments, so why passing them in the first place?

Comment: A _declaration_ as `int main();` does not indicate no arguments like `int main(void);` would. A declaration with no parameters indicates _no info_ about the parameters.  It will match a later _definition_ such as `int main(void) {` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {` , ...